# Django: python manage.py migrate - Выдаёт ошибку

Tags: python, django, django-model

Создал две модели, хотел подключить поле категории к модели Category, но выдаёт ошибку при команде python manage.py migrate (makemigrations делал)

models.py

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=154, unique=True, verbose_name='Категория')


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=99, verbose_name='Название')
    price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Цена')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/images/', verbose_name='Фотография')
    availability = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Наличие')
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='прочее', verbose_name='Категория')
```

ValueError

```py
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, contenttypes, products, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying products.0004_category_alter_product_options_product_category...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Timofey\patterson-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1822, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'прочее'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Timofey\patterson-project\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Timofey\patterson-project\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Timofey\patterson-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 425, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Timofey\patterson-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Timofey\patterson-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 373, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Timofey\patterson-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 417, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Timofey\patterson-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 90, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Timofey\patterson-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 253, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\Timofey\patterson-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 126, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Timofey\patterson-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 156, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Timofey\patterson-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 236, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Timofey\patterson-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 125, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Timofey\patterson-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 100, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_field(
  File "C:\Timofey\patterson-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 330, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_field=field)
  File "C:\Timofey\patterson-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 191, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(create_field)
  File "C:\Timofey\patterson-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 336, in effective_default
    return field.get_db_prep_save(self._effective_default(field), self.connection)
  File "C:\Timofey\patterson-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 992, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)
  File "C:\Timofey\patterson-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 839, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "C:\Timofey\patterson-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2461, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Timofey\patterson-project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1824, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'прочее'.
```

Comment: я подозреваю, что в классе Category вам нужно вернуть представление модели, потому что иначе, вроде, foreignkey будет обращаться к полю с уникальным идентификатором.

Comment: Не понял, можно поподробнее, пожалуйста?

Comment: Покажите код текущей и предыдущей миграции для поля category

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в моделях в классе Category сделать так:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=154, unique=True, verbose_name='Категория')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'
```

Comment: Спасибо, но я исправил ошибку используя null=True в модели Product поле category